# Save a list in a property in an entity in xodus

Tags: xodus

I have not found how to save a general list of primitive types, e.g. ints, or strings, in a property of an entity. I might have missed something obvious...

https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores described that "only Java primitive types, Strings, and ComparableSet values can be used by default".

It seems not hard to convert an `Iterable` into a `ComparableSet`. However it is a `Set`.

I will take a look into `PersistentEntityStore.registerCustomPropertyType()` to see if that helps. I just feel wrong to do that to just save a list of integers.

Links seemed to be able to serve as a way of saving a list of `Entity`s. But it seems there is no `addProperty()` counterpart to `addLink()`.

Appreciated if some one can share a way or a workaround for this, or maybe why this is not supported.

Thanks

Comment: Allowing duplicates in a list is a must, right?

Comment: Yes. What I am looking for is a general `List`-like structure. So both duplicates and order.

Comment: It seems there is no direct ways to persist a list. The entity links as I tested are acting like a `Set`, with no duplicates allowed. What I came up with was to implement a `ComparableList` and a `ComparableListBinding`, mostly adapted from the built-in `ComparableSet` and `ComparableSetBinding`, then register them with `.registerCustomPropertyType()`.

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov I found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-355. I don't seem to be able to see comments in the issue, so I have no idea what happened. But https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/commit/680c14f suggested `ComparableSet` resulted from it. Why a `Set` was used instead of a `List`? I have not read a lot, but from `ComparableSet` and `ComparableSetBinding`, it seemed only `getMinimum()`, `getMaximum()` and `minus()` would benefit from a `Set`. However I think those should not be hard to come by with a `List`, while ordering and duplicates are banned in a `Set`. Your thoughts?

Comment: Entity properties allow searching for entities by a property value or in a range of values. ComparableSet allows to define a property with several values, single property cannot have several equal values, and all values are naturally sorted (as Comparables). That's why a set, not a list. Do you need to search for entites by a value in a list?

Comment: Yes, it'd be great as what's being done with `ComparableSet`. I did notice that `ComparableSet` got some special treatment when indexing, e.g. https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/e54b983/entity-store/src/main/java/jetbrains/exodus/entitystore/tables/PropertiesTable.java#L174. However, the underlying key-value store does do sorting and de-duplicating anyway. So for indexing, a set doesn't seem required for functionality. For serialization, `ComparableSetBinding`'s `writeObject()` and `readObject()` don't seem to need a set particularly. My observations so far, may miss things I don't know.

Comment: I'd suggest then a hybrid scheme. Serialize a list to binary stream or string and save it using `setBlob(..)` or `setBlobString(..)`. For searching, create entities of another type having single property which is equal to a value in a list. Those entities would be like an enum or a dictionary of values. Use `addLink(..)` and `deleteLink(..)` to maintain links to dictionary items. Source entities (having a value in their lists) could be found using `StoreTransaction.findLinks(String, Entity, String)` method.

Comment: @Vin can you share your solution?

Comment: @quarks I posted one of my attempts on the issue below. Hopefully it might be of some use.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, one workaround I came up with was to create a `ComparableList`, by adopting code from `ComparableSet`.

The idea was to make a list that is able to convert to and from an `ArrayByteIterable`, and register it with `.registerCustomPropertyType()`. To do that, 2 classes are needed, `ComparableList` and `ComparableListBinding`. I'm sharing one iteration I used at the bottom. By the way, I made them immutable, comparing to the mutable `ComparableSet`. The newly implemented types should be registered once in a transaction of the store before using them.

That should allow you to store and retrieve a list. However the items in `ComparableList` would not get indexed as they would when saved in a `ComparableSet` -- there are some special treatment for `ComparableSet` in the entity store implementation. So without modifying the library, indexing would work only with hacks like creating another property to just index the values.

I was considering to implement a different entity store that could better support lists, on top of the xodus key-value store, bypassing the xodus entity store entirely. That might be a better solution to the list issue we are talking about here.

---

`ComparableList`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ComparableList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<ComparableList<T>>,
    Iterable<T> {
  @Nonnull
  private final ImmutableList<T> list;

  public ComparableList(@Nonnull final Iterable<T> iterable) {
    list = ImmutableList.copyOf(iterable);
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(@Nonnull final ComparableList<T> other) {
    final Iterator<T> thisIt = list.iterator();
    final Iterator<T> otherIt = other.list.iterator();
    while (thisIt.hasNext() && otherIt.hasNext()) {
      final int cmp = thisIt.next().compareTo(otherIt.next());
      if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
      }
    }
    if (thisIt.hasNext()) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (otherIt.hasNext()) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return list.iterator();
  }

  @Nullable
  public Class<T> getItemClass() {
    final Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();
    return it.hasNext() ? (Class<T>) it.next().getClass() : null;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return list.toString();
  }
}
```

`ComparableListBinding`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public class ComparableListBinding extends ComparableBinding {

  public static final ComparableListBinding INSTANCE = new ComparableListBinding();

  private ComparableListBinding() {}

  @Override
  public ComparableList readObject(@NotNull final ByteArrayInputStream stream) {
    final int valueTypeId = stream.read() ^ 0x80;
    final ComparableBinding itemBinding = ComparableValueType.getPredefinedBinding(valueTypeId);
    final ImmutableList.Builder<Comparable> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
    while (stream.available() > 0) {
      builder.add(itemBinding.readObject(stream));
    }
    return new ComparableList(builder.build());
  }

  @Override
  public void writeObject(@NotNull final LightOutputStream output,
      @NotNull final Comparable object) {
    final ComparableList<? extends Comparable> list = (ComparableList) object;
    final Class itemClass = list.getItemClass();
    if (itemClass == null) {
      throw new ExodusException("Attempt to write empty ComparableList");
    }
    final ComparableValueType type = ComparableValueType.getPredefinedType(itemClass);
    output.writeByte(type.getTypeId());
    final ComparableBinding itemBinding = type.getBinding();
    list.forEach(o -> itemBinding.writeObject(output, o));
  }

  /**
   * De-serializes {@linkplain ByteIterable} entry to a {@code ComparableList} value.
   *
   * @param entry {@linkplain ByteIterable} instance
   * @return de-serialized value
   */
  public static ComparableList entryToComparableList(@NotNull final ByteIterable entry) {
    return (ComparableList) INSTANCE.entryToObject(entry);
  }

  /**
   * Serializes {@code ComparableList} value to the {@linkplain ArrayByteIterable} entry.
   *
   * @param object value to serialize
   * @return {@linkplain ArrayByteIterable} entry
   */
  public static ArrayByteIterable comparableSetToEntry(@NotNull final ComparableList object) {
    return INSTANCE.objectToEntry(object);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you mean you were able to make saving work but `find`ing based on what's in the List you were not able to make it work? I mean when you said *So without modifying the library, indexing would work only with hacks like creating another property to just index the values.*

Comment: Same case with this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-833

Comment: This is about `find()`. But XD-833 seems to be about a different issue? -- `ComparableSet` could not serialize a custom `Comparable` type. The line I said was about https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/e54b983/entity-store/src/main/java/jetbrains/exodus/entitystore/tables/PropertiesTable.java#L174, which is how the index is created, and is called when saving a property. In that, `String`s are lower cased before indexing, and `ComparableSet` iterates each item for indexing, while other primitive types are indexed directly.

Comment: I realized I made a typo, which was probably the cause of our confusions here. Sorry for that! Copy-pasta failed. I just struck out the error and corrected in the paragraph containing the line you referenced.

Comment: XD-833 is about serializing a custom type and also be able to query it later